# Android seekbar anyway to set different style attributes byclicking a button?

Tags: android, styles, progress, seekbar

I'm now trying to change the style of a seek bar when users click the button.
I do have 2 progress drawables formed with XML, but when I use `setProgressDrawable()` function, it totally ignores the style I added on xml and just sets a drawable.

Is there anyway to change the style programmatically by Java code?

Or is it possible to change the color of secondary progress without touching style?
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have two XML drawables.

progress_bar.xml

```
< layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    < item android:id="@android:id/background">
        < shape>
            < gradient 
                    android:startColor="#10ffffff"
                    android:endColor="#10ffffff"
                    android:angle="270" />                                  
    < /shape>
    < /item>
    < item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        < clip>
           < shape>
              < gradient
                    android:startColor="#10ffffff"
                    android:endColor="#10ffffff"
                    android:angle="270" />
           < /shape>
        < /clip>
    < /item>
    < item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        < clip>
           < shape>
              < gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/C_Orange1"
                    android:endColor="@color/C_Orange1"
                    android:angle="270" />
           < /shape>

        < /clip>
    < /item>
< /layer-list>
```

another one is created with almost the same code except the position of  `@android:id/secondaryProgress` and `@android:id/progress` 
called progress_bar_timeshift.xml

```
< layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    < item android:id="@android:id/background">
        < shape>
            < gradient 
                    android:startColor="#10ffffff"
                    android:endColor="#10ffffff"
                    android:angle="270" />                                  
    < /shape>
    < /item>
    < item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        < clip>
           < shape>
              < gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/C_Orange1"
                    android:endColor="@color/C_Orange1"
                    android:angle="270" />
           < /shape>
        < /clip>
    < /item>
    < item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        < clip>
           < shape>
              < gradient
                    android:startColor="#10ffffff"
                    android:endColor="#10ffffff"
                    android:angle="270" />
           < /shape>

        < /clip>
    < /item>
< /layer-list>
```

and I have two custom styles

```
<style name="Widget.SeekBar" parent="android:style/Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/seekbar_thumb_button</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">13dp</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.SeekBar2" parent="android:style/Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar_timeshift</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar_timeshift</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/seekbar_thumb_button</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">13dp</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
</style>
```

I want to change from `Widget.SeekBar` to `Widget.SeekBar2` when clicking a button. is it possible?
What I really need is to change color of secondary progress and primary progress when clicking the button (not Thumb).

**++++++++++++++++++++++++++**

ok here's image

[Original SeekBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RvB6.png)

this is the first seekbar that I currently have.

Now, when I press button, the secondary progress will be set, 
and I want to change color of primary progress without any effect to secondary progress.

like this

[wanted look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrJF6.png)

the orange part on the second image is the part of secondary progress.
When I use colorfilter, it changes all the color in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below library for changing style programatically on click event:

https://github.com/ahmedrizwan/SeekBarCompat

Comment: pls show me image of which type of seekbar you want ?